# WKWebView load webpage with special characters

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview, idn

I've got a wkwebview that works as a browser. I can't manage to load addresses with special characters such as "[http://www.håbo.se](http://www.h%C3%A5bo.se)" (swedish character).

I'm using:

```
parsedUrl = [parsedUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

which is promising as it creates an address that looks like follows:
http://www.h%c3%a5bo.se/

If I enter that in Chrome it works. But when I try to load it in the wkwebview i get the following (I can load all other pages):

Here's the full NSError printed

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x7f82ca502290>, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.h%c3%a5bo.se/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.h%c3%a5bo.se/, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f82ca692200 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.h%c3%a5bo.se/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.h%c3%a5bo.se/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}},
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is complicated. From [this article](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/):

**Resolving a domain name**

> If the string that represents the domain name is not in Unicode, the
>   user agent converts the string to Unicode. It then performs some
>   normalization functions on the string to eliminate ambiguities that
>   may exist in Unicode encoded text.
>
> Normalization involves such things as converting uppercase characters
>   to lowercase, reducing alternative representations (eg. converting
>   half-width kana to full), eliminating prohibited characters (eg.
>   spaces), etc.
>
> Next, the user agent converts each of the labels (ie. pieces of text
>   between dots) in the Unicode string to a punycode representation. A
>   special marker ('xn--') is added to the beginning of each label
>   containing non-ASCII characters to show that the label was not
>   originally ASCII. The end result is not very user friendly, but
>   accurately represents the original string of characters while using
>   only the characters that were previously allowed for domain names.

For example, following domain name:

> JP納豆.例.jp

converts to next representation:

> xn--jp-cd2fp15c.xn--fsq.jp

You can use [following code](https://github.com/OnionBrowser/iOS-OnionBrowser/blob/master/OnionBrowser/NSStringPunycodeAdditions.h) to perform this conversion.

**Resolving a path**

> If the string is input by the user or stored in a non-Unicode
>   encoding, it is converted to Unicode, normalized using Unicode
>   Normalization Form C, and encoded using the UTF-8 encoding.
>
> The user agent then converts the non-ASCII bytes to percent-escapes.

For example, following path:

> /dir1/引き割り.html

converts to next representation:

> /dir1/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A.html

For this purpose, you may use following code:

```
path = [URL.path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Note that `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is deprecated, because each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.

**Putting it all together**

Resulting code:

```
@implementation NSURL (Normalization)

- (NSURL*)normalizedURL {
    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:self resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
    components.host = [components.host IDNAEncodedString]; // from https://github.com/OnionBrowser/iOS-OnionBrowser/blob/master/OnionBrowser/NSStringPunycodeAdditions.h
    components.path = [components.path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
    return components.URL;
}

@end
```

Unfortunately, actual URL "normalization" is more complicated - you need to handle all remaining URL components too. But I hope I've answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't think that it was needed to convert to IDN. I used this:
https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/NSURL-IDN

And converted the string before creating the NSURL, and it works like a charm.